# Configure environment specific variables using vue-cli

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I am trying to figure out how to deploy my vue app that was generated with vue-cli 3 to production. I plan on hosting it as static files (that is no server side code). I need to set certain variables in my code based on the current environment (dev vs production). These include api-urls and authentication information (none of which is secret).

What is the best way of doing this?

Here are the config docs for vue-cli 3: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/

Comment: Please share your webpack configuration. If you don't have one, you'll need one in order to use the `DefinePlugin`. (https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)

Comment: The webpack config is hidden since I am using vue-cli but it can be configured using vue.config.js - file.  The possible options for this file is listed in the link included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to start the variable names with VUE_APP (https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html)

Answer (score 14):

You can just add your variables to existing `DefinePlugin` config with `chainWebpack`:

```js
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .plugin('define')
      .tap(args => {
          args[0] = {
             ...args[0],
             "MY_API_URL": JSON.stringify(process.env.URL),
             // other stuff
          }
          return args
       })
  }
}
```

And configure environment variables in `.env`.

Answer (score 4):

To make the config values part of `process.env` a slight update to Max Sinev's answer would be

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugin("define").tap(args => {
      let _base = args[0]["process.env"];
      args[0]["process.env"] = {
        ..._base,
        "API_URL": JSON.stringify(process.env.URL),
      };
      return args;
    });
  }
}
```

Now `API_URL` can be accessed as `precess.env.API_URL`

Comment: As I tried, now API_URL seems can be accesed as `API_URL`